# insert item at multiple indices into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, insert, indices

For example I have an array arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and I want to add the number 12 at position 0, 5, 8 and 9.

To achieve this I tried

```
extension Array {
    mutating func remove(_ newElement: Element, at indexes: [Int]) {
        for index in indexes.sorted(by: >) {
            insert(_ newElement: Element, at: index)
        }
     }
  }
```

But then I get the error: Ambiguous reference to member 'insert(_:at:) in the 4th line. Is it possible to do this in this way ? 
I use Xcode 9.2

Comment: `insert(newElement, at: index)` instead? You are mixing method declaration and method call syntax. Also calling a method remove and doing insert, that's strange.

Comment: The plural of index is indices, but then you knew that because of your question title.

Comment: It seems like it's working for me after the minor fix in your code. I renamed your method to 'add' instead of 'remove' and the proper way of calling insert is: insert( newElement, at: index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
extension Array  {

    mutating func add(_ newElement: Element, at indexes: [Int]) {

        for index in indexes {
            insert(newElement, at: index)
        }
    }
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

array.add(12, at: [0,5,8,9])

print(array) // [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 5, 6, 12, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your insert function is not currently receiving an element argument. You are using the insert function, not declaring it. I also renamed your function for use clarification.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

extension Array {
    mutating func add(_ newElement: Element, at indices: [Int]) {
        for index in indices(by: >) {
            insert(newElement, at: index)
        }
    }
}

arr.add(12, at: [0, 5, 8, 9])
print(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
extension Array{
    mutating func replaceElements(atPositions: [Int], withElement: Element){
        for item in atPositions{
            self.remove(at: item)
            self.insert(withElement, at: item)
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that your don't necessarily need to use the `self` keyword; it was only used for clarity.

Comment: read the question carefully - it is about inserting number, not about replacing them